# How to get ALL the GCP folders from an Organization with `JAVA`?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-resource-manager

In my GCP organization which has following hierarchy `Org--> folder--> folder--> folder--> projects--> Resources`. I need to list folders and check if it has any subfolder and then eventually projects. Is there a way I can get what's down the folder tree(leaf being the folder having projects) given a folder id??

Comment: Yes, you can list the contents of an organization using the CLI `gcloud`, SDKs and APIs. What problem are you having? This link should help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

To list the resources that are in a folder you could use the command:

```
gcloud resource-manager folders list --organization=ORG-ID
```

Here you could review the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders#list) with more details about the command:

After that you could search the folder doen the folder you require using the flag --folders with the ID of the folder that you got with the first command you could create a script to automate for this.

Also you could grant the roll as power owner as organization level and use the command:

```
gcloud beta projects list
```

this [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/projects/list) will list all the projects you could also save it in a file. Using the information of the file you could describe each project to review their parent type and parent ID's.